# Ajax is running on both cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

I have created an input box when i confirm its submitting the value and getting the success alert, but i am getting success on cancel button too?

```
swal({
    title: " Asking price for " + askData[0] + "?",
    text: "If you are sure press OK or edit this text",
    type: "input",
    inputType: "text",
    inputValue: "Hello " + askData[1] + ", I am interested in buying your " + askData[0] + " of Variety :" + askData[3] + ". Please update the Price!",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true
}, function (inputValue) {
    if (inputValue === "") {
        swal.showInputError("Please write something !");
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: urlEnq,
        type: "GET"
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'saveUserMessage',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            fieldUserId: fieldUserId,
            filedUserCompanyId: filedUserCompanyId,
            message: inputValue
        },

    })
        .done(function (data) {
            swal("Done!", "Your message has been successfully sent.", "success");
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            swal.showInputError("Please write something !");
        });
```

Comment: what is the value of the `inputValue` variable when you click cancel?

Comment: inputValue is used for input value field , A text box.

Comment: yes we know that, what is the actual value of the variable? You are doing an if on that variable to decide if you need to do the ajax call

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kamleshbisht/b3u9monk/2/ here is a small example for the same

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) the value of the variable passed into the callback function will be `false` and not `''` when cancel is clicked.

I have updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3u9monk/3/) to show this, please see updated code below:

```
$('button.delete-account').click(function (e) {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure you want to delete your account?",
        text: "If you are sure, type in your password:",
        type: "input",
        inputType: "password",
        showCancelButton: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function (typedPassword) {
        if (typedPassword === false) {
            return;
        }
        if (typedPassword === "") {
            swal.showInputError("You need to type in your password in order to do this!");
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/delete-account",
            data: { password: typedPassword },
            type: "POST"
        }).done(function (data) {
            swal("Deleted!", "Your account has been deleted!", "success");
        }).error(function (data) {
            swal.showInputError("Your password is wrong!");
        });
    });
});
```